# virtual host preventing default server

Tags: 16.04, apache2, virtualhost

I have a home server I use for development and something I'm battling is sometimes I enter one url and it loads the wrong website,

for example:

> https://dev.demoapp.com => https://dev.demoapp.com (Correct)
>
> http://dev.demoapp.com => http://dev.mysite.com (Incorrect)

so I went to see what Apache is loading everything as:

> VirtualHost configuration:
>
> *:443 is a NameVirtualHost
>
> default server dev.demoapp.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.demoapp.com.conf:1)
>
> port 443 namevhost dev.demoapp.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.demoapp.com.conf:1)
>
> port 443 namevhost dev.test.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.test.com.conf:1)
>
> *:80 is a NameVirtualHost
>
> default server dev.mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.mysite.com.conf:1)
>
> port 80 namevhost dev.mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.mysite.com.conf:1)
>
> port 80 namevhost dev.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.local.com.conf:1)

I noticed that certain sites are showing up twice, and I don't know how its doing that.

how can I make it so that http://dev.mysite.com either redirects to https or just tell the user its an invalid url(prefer to have it redirect honestly)

Comment: problem I think hes is facing is he is trying to use subdomains such as `www.mysite.com` and `forum.mysite.com` ... as far as I have used it .. that is not possible if doing local .. for me `http:localhost` would show me `www.mysite.com` and `forum.localhost` would show me `www.mysite.com` instead of `forum.mysite.com` but if I do it over the net .. I get the respective sites showing up properly

Comment: see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define a separate `<VirtualHost *:80>` container, with `ServeName /dev.demoapp.com` or add a `ServerAlias /dev.demoapp.com` line in the appropoiate existing VirtualHost container.

You can NOT serve the same VirtualHosts with different ports from ONE `<VirtualHost ..>` container, unless you work with wildcard for port.

I usually work with Include files for all directives that are shared between VirtualHosts and only put the specific directives, like SSL* in the individual `<VirtualHost ..:443>` directives (I even put each VIrtualHost in a separate Include file.)

As of Apache httpd-2.3.11 there is no effective NameVirtualHost directive (any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

Furthermore, there is no DEFAULT VirtualHost, the first `<VirtualHost>` directive found is de-facto the default, meaning all client requests, whose HTTP_HOST Header is not explicitly defined as `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`in a separate `<VirtualHost>` is being served the first Virualhost configuration.

If you want to implement a 'Default' VirtualHost' you can put either a `<VirtualHost *:80>` container in in the central httpd.conf file BEFORE you include any further files (before `IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` or whatever), or you write a vhost include file which comes at the top of your list, eg. 0_default-vhost.conf, with `<VirtualHost *:*>` or `<VirtualHost *>`, please try out, which one works.